# systemd-analyze info for previous system boots

Tags: boot, systemd, 21.04

The `systemd-analyze` command's `time`, `blame`, etc. options can be used to determine the "system boot performance" by outputting some timing information about its *current boot*. Is there a method to get the same information for the system's previous boots?

Comment: I think that is a no unless you set up a script to write the output of systemd-analyze to a file after each boot. There is nothing in the man pages about this

Comment: Is `dmesg  -T` offering what you want to see?

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary "solution" I added the following to my *shutdown* script (not to the *startup* script to be on the safe side):

```
 echo $(/usr/bin/who -b ; /usr/bin/systemd-analyze) >>/var/local/sa.log
```